# Object of custom class is not getting store in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I want to add object to NSMutableArray but after writing following code i am getting benchmarkArray NIL. Where is the mistake help me please

```
    [benchmark setBenchmarkTitle:self.benchmarkTitle.text];
    [benchmark setBenchmarkDescription:self.benchmarkDescription.text];
    [benchmarkArray addObject:benchmark];
```

My Benchmark class is:

```
@interface Benchmark : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *bid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *benchmarkTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *benchmarkDescription;

-(id)initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder;
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder;

@end

@implementation Benchmark

@synthesize bid;
@synthesize benchmarkTitle;
@synthesize benchmarkDescription;

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {

    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        bid = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"id"];
        benchmarkTitle = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"benchmarkTitle"];
        benchmarkDescription = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"benchmarkDescription"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:bid forKey:@"id"];
    [encoder encodeObject:benchmarkTitle forKey:@"benchmarkTitle"];
    [encoder encodeObject:benchmarkDescription forKey:@"benchmarkDescription"];
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you sure that coder is properly initialised?

Comment: he says benchmarkArray is nil, not empty

Comment: @peko i have already add this line at ViewDidLoad
benchmarkArray = [[NSMutableArray]alloc] init];

Comment: @Ramy Al Zuhouri yes i am using ARC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forgot to allocate and initialize

```
benchmarkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with your BenchMark Class.

Your problem lies in the class where you have created `benchMarkArray`.

After making property of it, you need to initialise it in `init/awakeFromNib/viewDidLoad` method as :

```
benchMarkArray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
```

or,

```
benchmarkArray=[NSArray new];
```

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    //set category/benchmark class object
    self.category = [[Category alloc] init];
    self.benchmark = [[Benchmark alloc] init];
    
}
i have already initialized it